# Не получается создать соединение к Dbeaver и pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin4, dbeaver, connect

[image: Вот что выскакивает в dbeaver]

Не получается создать соединение, но суть в чем: Как только я перезагрузил пк , в dbeaver у меня получилось создать соединение , но через минуту оно пропало, вылетала какая то ошибка(уже не помню какая, но что то связано с той, которая на фото) . Так же пробовал создать в pgadmin4 , но программа писала мол потеряно соединение. И прикол в том, что когда у меня начал на минуту работать dbeaver, я попробовал запустить и pgadmin4, и о чудо, все получилось, но ненадолго.. так же через минуту опять вылетала ошибка которая была и до этого...

Comment: *но через минуту оно пропало* Файрвол опомнился?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.